# How to stop this thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, runnable

In my application i am using this thread to rotate the Second hand on the clock. But the Problem is while i close the activity, the thread is still remain run. I want to stop the thread so it can not effect the Bettry of the device.

Below is my Activity code where i am rotating the Clock's Second Hand:

```
 public class ClockActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button chimeBtn;
    private ImageView img;
    private Thread myThread = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clock_layout);


        Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
        myThread = new Thread(runnable);
        myThread.start();

        chimeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chimeBtn);
        chimeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.chimeBtn:
                playSound(R.raw.one_bell);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void playSound(int resources){

         MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resources);
            mp.start();


    }

    private void doPlay(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("log_tag", "this is seocond thread");

            }
        }).start();
    }
    public void doRotate() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + "::" + seconds;
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Log is here Time is now" + curTime);
                    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgsecond);
                    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation((seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

                    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                    img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error msg is " + e.toString());

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {       
            System.out.println("Back Key Press");
            if (myThread != null) {

                   myThread.interrupt(); //says that the myThread should stop 
                   try{ 
                           myThread.join(); //make this myThread wait for the other myThread to  finish before returning
                           myThread = new Thread();
                           myThread = null;
                   }catch(InterruptedException ie){ 
                           //handle the case if the thread.join is interrupt 
                           //don't know if this will ever happen, if it can... throw a runtime exception?, or reinterrupt? 
                           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                           //   reinterrupt because thrown exception cleared interrupt and hope it's handled elsewhere 
                   } 

            }
            System.out.println("Back Key Press");
            return true;       
        }       
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);     
    } 

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){

        System.out.println("OnDestroy");

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    // Log.v("log_tag", "Roate is going");
                    doRotate();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    //doPlay();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                    // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error is " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't `myThread.join()` on the UI thread since it will block until the Thread finished and your App might ANR. Also `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` will try to interrupt the UI thread which is really bad.

You can put `MyThread.interrupt()` in `onDestroy`, `onPause` or `onStop` (+ recreate the Thread in the corresponding start callback)

Comment: Ok i Have put the code myThread.interrupt() in onDestroy. but still it not stop the thread.

Comment: you should assume that `catch (InterruptedException e)` is the signal to stop your thread. If you catch that then `isInterrupted()` will return false afterwards (afaik)

Comment: Well Thanks for the Answer. But still not getting to Stop the thread. Will you please give any Sample code to do it ?

Comment: put a `return;` in the catch block and maybe add some `Log.d()` debug to your thread / onDestroy to see when / if the methods are called.

Comment: @Suvan Roy's answer works for me but it kill all the process of my app. So i was not able to create the service in My app. but now with your Answer i am able to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try this code in your activity -

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

When you exit from your application, your application process is not actually destroyed. If you destroy your process, all child processes(all your child threads) will be destroyed.

Comment: Nice One. Using this i got my thread successfully stop. But will it be effected on the other resources of my App ?

Comment: No guy, it will stop only your current application, it doesn't hamper another resources.

Comment: I mean about to other resources on the same application. I mean i am going to store some Values to the shared Preference.  So will it be effected on it ?

Comment: I don't get your question actually. You are going to store and it will effect on it. Android is linux based os. Same kill process is as on linux command behavior. You can forcefully close your app in "setting-> manage application -> select your app _ force close. This is code by grammatically close your app.

Comment: Its not like that. I want to Set the Alarm to my App. So if i Kill the Process then will it be effect to my app ?

Comment: you want to mean that if you close your app then other section of your code will be effected or not?
Yes, it'll destroy your process as well as your child process(child thread). If you don't want to do that, then use a boolen flag and set it in while condition in your thread. And set it false in the onDestroy method.

Comment: Please update the code with this new logic. As previous one is destroy the all process of my application. And i am going to create the service in the app. that service is also destroy with your code.

Comment: @SuvamRoy not grammatically but programmatically

Answer (score 4):

Ok, that means you want to create a service that will have been running in background. One thing is that service is one type of thread, if it will run in background that will drain your device battery power. So, if you kill your process then the thread as well as your service will destroy. So, stop your thread like -

```
boolean running = true;

public void run() {
   while(running) {
       // your working code...
   }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    running = false;
}
```

When you exit your app, the thread will stop. And the other will stay running, that is your service. Don't try to stop your thread forcefully, or suspend. It is deprecated, if your while loop of the thread breaks, then it will automatically destroy your thread according to JVM rules.
Hope it will help you.
Have fun...

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem the thread is blocked in native function call, for example in InputStream.read(). killProcess()  helps, but not for my case - I do not want to kill whole app, I just need to kill that java thread...