# Closing the entire application with close button

Tags: android, android-activity

For my app if I use `finish()` then it will close activity **A**. For the activity stack like **A**->**B**->**C**(*currently visible*) if I use `finish()` in **C** it will close **C**, not **A** or **B** and **B** resumes.

In such cases if **I need to close all the activities at a glance** by clicking a Close button in activity **C** then what is the solution ? Does Android provide any technique to achieve this ?

---

**NOTE:** I found a solution [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927301/closing-of-activity-in-android) which is partially helpful, not enough to solve my problem. Though you may get some idea(s) from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, on close button click send a broadcast to your home activity then then call this :

```
// Inside broadcast recevier do this, it wont allow then write below code in a separate function and call this. 
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

It will work surely, i have already done before and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link it will help you

[Finish all previous activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this will clear all the activities on top of home.

Comment: I want to close A,B & C at a glance.. not only B & C. So will it work ??